# Terminal escape sequences in GNU Screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, terminal-emulator, escape-sequences

So I'm quite confused with the concept of escape sequences in a terminal (or terminal emulator to be more precise) and how they relate to the screen `bindkey` command. I was looking at some sample `.screenrc` file that I found on the internet where I saw the following configuration:

```
# switch windows with F3 (prev) and F4 (next)
bindkey "^[OR" prev
bindkey "^[OS" next

# switch layouts with Ctrl+F3 (prev layout) and Ctrl+F4 (next)
bindkey "^[O1;5R" layout prev
bindkey "^[O1;5S" layout next
```

I have no idea why, for example, the sequence `^[0R` means `F3` and the sequence `^[01;5R` means `Ctrl+F3`. Is there a table for such sequences?

Also these sequences remind me of the sequences used to configure the colors in a terminal prompt (e.g using the `$PS1` env variable) like `\[\033[0m\]` for reset and `\[\033[30m\]` for foreground black. Is there actually any relationship between these two "code sequences" or is it just my pure imagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

Yes, these are ANSI escape codes.

You can see a list of ANSI escape codes for VT100 here:
http://www.braun-home.net/michael/info/misc/VT100_commands.htm but
there is a quicker way - in your terminal emulator press
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and then
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> for example and you will see this:

```
$ ^[[1;5R
```

In `man bash` it says:

```
   quoted-insert (C-q, C-v)
          Add the next character typed to the line verbatim.  This
          is how to insert characters like C-q, for example.
```

Notice that `^[` itself is <kbd>Escape</kbd> in the output of
`quoted-insert` and you can study this answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108014/72304 to learn where this
notation comes from.

To understand it better - as you already know there are some [ANSI
escape codes for selecting
color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) that use
`Escape` key.  There are several methods to enter a literal
`Escape` - we can for example use octal notation as we know that
`Escape` is \033 in ASCII table:

```
printf "\033[1;34mThis is a blue text.\n\033[0m"
```

We can also use `\e` backslash escape that some implementations of
`printf` understand:

```
printf "\e[1;34mThis is a blue text.\n\e[0m"
```

But you can also use `quoted-insert` to insert a literal `Escape` -
point your cursor in place of `\e`, remove it, press
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and then press
<kbd>Escape</kbd>. You'll get this:

```
printf "^[[1;34mThis is a blue text.\n^[[0m"
```

Notice that when you do that in your terminal emulator `^[` will be
treated as a single character. Copying the above line and pasting into
your terminal emulator will not work though as you will get 2 separate
characters instead of one.